# How to add active state for "nested" accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

I found this efficient and practical nested accordion using 'ul' at codepen here: https://codepen.io/brenden/pen/Kwbpyj

It's as following:

```js
$('.toggle').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
  
    var $this = $(this);
  
    if ($this.next().hasClass('show')) {
        $this.next().removeClass('show');
        $this.next().slideUp(350);
    } else {
        $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').removeClass('show');
        $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').slideUp(350);
        $this.next().toggleClass('show');
        $this.next().slideToggle(350);
    }
});
```

```css
url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico|Open+Sans:300,400,600');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.active {
  text-decoration: underline !important;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
.description {
  margin: 1em auto 2.25em;
}
body {
  width: 40%;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 1.5em auto;
  color: #333;
}
h1 {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
ul .inner {
  padding-left: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}
ul .inner.show {
  /*display: block;*/
}
ul li {
  margin: .5em 0;
}
ul li a.toggle {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.78);
  color: #fefefe;
  padding: .75em;
  border-radius: 0.15em;
  transition: background .3s ease;
}
ul li a.toggle:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>A Cool Accordion</h1>

<p class="description">
  You could simply toggle the .show class (if display: block is uncommented in the CSS) in JavaScript, but you'll lose the animation.
</p>

<ul class="accordion">
  <li>
    <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Item 1</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>Option 1</li>
      <li>Option 2</li>
      <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Item 2</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>Option 1</li>
      <li>Option 2</li>
      <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Item 3</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="toggle">Open Inner</a>
        <div class="inner">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempus placerat fringilla. Duis a elit et dolor laoreet volutpat. Aliquam ultrices mauris id mattis imperdiet. Aenean cursus ultrices justo et varius. Suspendisse aliquam orci id dui dapibus
            blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed risus velit, pellentesque eu enim ac, ultricies pretium felis.
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="toggle">Open Inner #2</a>
        <div class="inner">
          <p>
            Children will automatically close upon closing its parent.
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
      
      <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Item 4</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="toggle">Technically any number of nested elements</a>
        <ul class="inner">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="toggle">Another nested element</a>
            <div class="inner">
              <p>
                As long as the inner element has inner as one of its classes then it will be toggled.
              </p>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempus placerat fringilla. Duis a elit et dolor laoreet volutpat. Aliquam ultrices mauris id mattis imperdiet. Aenean cursus ultrices justo et varius. Suspendisse aliquam orci id dui dapibus
                blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed risus velit, pellentesque eu enim ac, ultricies pretium felis.
              </p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      
      <li>Option 2</li>
      
      <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But it doesn't support active state by adding for example '.active' class for the opened title.

Also Look at the "Item 3". When you click on nested 'a', the '.active' class of 'a' inside the active 'li' parents are removed. The point here is how can i keep them active while i click on nested 'a'?

So can you help me to do that?

Comment: Just remove and add the `.active` class in the `.click()` method.

Comment: Hi Morad Hamdy what you exactly want to do with that ".active" class as it's working on the ".show" class, as you will see in code you will find that if the accordion has show class then it's active

Comment: @Polyov Every 'a' has class '.toggle'. What i want is to add is '.active' class for the clicked 'a', and then removed when clicking another similar 'a'

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara
The '.show' is added to the next 'ul', but i want to add '.active' class to the title which is the clicked 'a'

Comment: @MoradHamdy i have already given answer for that please check that below in answers

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara .. I have already replied you down at your participation :) .. "Nalin Aggarwal" has made the specific style i asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following code.

**Jquery** :

```
 $('.toggle').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();        
  var $this = $(this);  
  if ($this.next().hasClass('show')) {
    $this.next().removeClass('show');
    $this.parent().find('.active').removeClass('active')    
    $this.next().slideUp(350);
   } else {
    $this.parent().parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');       
    $this.parent('ul').find('.active').removeClass('active')
    $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').removeClass('show');
    $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').slideUp(350);
    $this.toggleClass('active');      
    $this.next().toggleClass('show');
    $this.next().slideToggle(350);
}
});
```

**CSS**

```
.active{
 background-color :blue !important;
}
```

It's adding active class in the markup :

```
<a class="toggle active" href="javascript:void(0);">Item 1</a>
```

Comment: I tried it, but it's not giving the specific purpose that i'm looking for. Here is how it looks using your suggested code: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1521160/4ebacb3b3a5c9d702d34e70d2fde6074

I want it to add class to the clicked one and remove from the others. But when i click on nested 'a', the active class keep the same for 'a' for all its parents 'li's

Comment: ohhkay !1 @MoradHamdy Updated my answer it works fine now

Comment: @Nilan Aggarwal .. Almost near, you did the most :) .. Look at the "Item 3". When you click on nested 'a', the '.active' class of 'a' that inside the active 'li' parents are removed. The point here is how can i keep them active while i click on nested 'a'?

Comment: so you want parent and child both with a active class, if child is clicked also ? and only the active child's not other. is that what you want @MoradHamdy

Comment: This is the preview of the current applied code: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1521461/4aef01dd2150adbba81f66534aae2b4c .. I want it to be like this: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1521462/56020d71c465a4596058d4135724b780 .. I want to keep the parents active.

Comment: Updated my answer check now, all the parent of the active child also active @MoradHamdy

Comment: There is some error. After opening nested childs, if you opened another 1st level, you will find that these nested opened still have '.active' class.

Comment: currently active childs with active parents have classes, on which level you do not want to have active class? @MoradHamdy

Comment: I'm not searching for disabling of adding class to specific level. The idea is implemented according to your last update. But when you back click for example on 'item 1', active class should be removed from all opened levels of 'item 4'. Try it to get the point. Just open the 3 nested levels for 'item 4', then directly open 'item 1'. You will find that active classes not removed from 'item 4'.

Comment: Thank you @Nalin Aggarwal :) .. It's perfect now!

Answer (score 0):

here i have updated the my answer as you have made a comment to my answer please check it out.

```js
$('.toggle').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
  
var $this = $(this);
 
if ($this.next().hasClass('show')) {
    $this.next().removeClass('show');
  
    /* JUST ADD HERE CLASS .ACTIVE */
    $this.removeClass("active");

    $this.next().slideUp(350);
} else {
    $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').removeClass('show');
   
    if($this.hasClass('parent')){
    
     /* JUST REMOVING HERE CLASS .ACTIVE FROM EARLY APPLIED */
      
      $this.parents(".accordion").find(".toggle").removeClass("active");         
      
    }else if($this.hasClass('child')){
    
     /* JUST REMOVING HERE CLASS .ACTIVE FROM EARLY APPLIED FOR CHILD */
     $this.parents(".accordion").find(".toggle.child").removeClass("active");
      
    }else{
    
     /* JUST REMOVING HERE CLASS .ACTIVE FROM EARLY APPLIED FOR CHILD OF CHILD */
     $this.parents(".accordion").find(".toggle.child-child").removeClass("active");
      
    }
  
    $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').slideUp(350);
    $this.next().toggleClass('show');
    
    /* JUST ADD HERE CLASS .ACTIVE */
    $this.addClass("active");      
    $this.next().slideToggle(350);
}
});
```

```css
url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico|Open+Sans:300,400,600');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.active {
  text-decoration: underline !important;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
.description {
  margin: 1em auto 2.25em;
}
body {
  width: 40%;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 1.5em auto;
  color: #333;
}
h1 {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
ul .inner {
  padding-left: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}
ul .inner.show {
  /*display: block;*/
}
ul li {
  margin: .5em 0;
}
ul li a.toggle {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.78);
  color: #fefefe;
  padding: .75em;
  border-radius: 0.15em;
  transition: background .3s ease;
}
ul li a.toggle:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

ul li a.toggle.active{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>A Cool Accordion</h1>

<p class="description">
  You could simply toggle the .show class (if display: block is uncommented in the CSS) in JavaScript, but you'll lose the animation.
</p>

<ul class="accordion">
  <li>
    <a class="toggle parent" href="javascript:void(0);">Item 1</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>Option 1</li>
      <li>Option 2</li>
      <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <a class="toggle parent" href="javascript:void(0);">Item 2</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>Option 1</li>
      <li>Option 2</li>
      <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <a class="toggle parent" href="javascript:void(0);">Item 3</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="toggle child">Open Inner</a>
        <div class="inner">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempus placerat fringilla. Duis a elit et dolor laoreet volutpat. Aliquam ultrices mauris id mattis imperdiet. Aenean cursus ultrices justo et varius. Suspendisse aliquam orci id dui dapibus
            blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed risus velit, pellentesque eu enim ac, ultricies pretium felis.
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="toggle child">Open Inner #2</a>
        <div class="inner">
          <p>
            Children will automatically close upon closing its parent.
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
      
      <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <a class="toggle parent" href="javascript:void(0);">Item 4</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="toggle child">Technically any number of nested elements</a>
        <ul class="inner">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="toggle child-child">Another nested element</a>
            <div class="inner">
              <p>
                As long as the inner element has inner as one of its classes then it will be toggled.
              </p>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempus placerat fringilla. Duis a elit et dolor laoreet volutpat. Aliquam ultrices mauris id mattis imperdiet. Aenean cursus ultrices justo et varius. Suspendisse aliquam orci id dui dapibus
                blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed risus velit, pellentesque eu enim ac, ultricies pretium felis.
              </p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      
      <li>Option 2</li>
      
      <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and here is the demo

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ueks8h2a/)

Comment: It's most near. There something still missed. For example, when you open "item 4", then open 1st nested, then open 2nd nested, then back close the  1st which has title "Technically any number of nested elements", then back open it, you will find that its nested one which has title "Another nested element" still has .active class although it should be removed. "Nalin Aggarwal" above has implemented the specific style i have asked for. Take a look to differentiate between the previews to get what i mean specifically.